# How to create dynamic scope variables in Angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, dynamic

[image: Here I added image]

I want create the screen like this.

The select dropdowns and input fields should not effect on each other (right now if I select company, that is showing as selected in the next set, it should not like that). How can I implement this?

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('newmonthlyplanning.controllers', [])

 .controller('newmonthlyplanningCtrl', ['$scope','$window', '$state', 'serviceFactory', '$compile', '$interval','targetPlanningService',
    function ($scope,$window,$state, serviceFactory, $compile,$interval,targetPlanningService) {
      
      $scope.status = '200';
         $scope.months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','June','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
        
         $scope.getAllSectors = function(){

              targetPlanningService.getAllsectors().then(function (response) {
              $scope.status = response.status;
              console.log(response);
              if (response.status === 200) {
                 $scope.sectors  =  response.data.sector_list;
              }
              else {
               
              }
            }, function (response) {       
              console.log(response);
               if (response.status === 401) {
                     $state.go('login');
                  }
            });

            };

             $scope.getcustomers = function(sector){
              
               console.log("selected sector ",sector);
              targetPlanningService.getAllCustomers(sector).then(function (response) {
              $scope.status = response.status;
              console.log(response);
              if (response.status === 200) {
                 $scope.customers  =  response.data.customer_list;
              }
              else {

              }
               
              
            }, function (response) {       
              console.log(response);
              if (response.status === 401) {
                     $state.go('login');
                  }
            });

            };

            $scope.targetDetails = [];
            $scope.getAllCompanies = function(){

              targetPlanningService.getAllCompanies().then(function (response) {
              $scope.status = response.status;
              console.log("companies---> ",response);
              if (response.status === 200) {
                 $scope.companies  =  response.data.companies;
                 
               $scope.targetDetails.push({'companies':$scope.companies,'sectors': $scope.sectors ,'customers': $scope.customers ,'targetss': $scope.targets});
              }
              else {

              }
                  
              
            }, function (response) {       
              console.log(response);
              if (response.status === 401) {
                         $state.go('login');
                       }  
            });

            };


             $scope.getAllproductIds = function(){
             /*  var details = {
                'company' : $scope.targetDetails.company,
                'sector'  : $scope.targetDetails.sector
               }
           console.log("details--->",details);*/
           console.log("$scope.targetDetails.company--->",$scope.targetDetails.company);
              targetPlanningService.getAllproductIds($scope.targetDetails.company).then(function (response) {
              $scope.status = response.status;
              console.log("product_ids--->",response);
              if (response.status === 200) {
                 $scope.productids  =  response.data.item_list;
              }
              else 
                {
                    
                  }
              
            }, function (response) {       
              console.log(response);
              if (response.status === 401) {
                     $state.go('login');
                  }
            });

            };

        $scope.targets = [{'pid': '','week1': '', 'week2': '','week3':'','week4':''}];
        
        var i=1;
     $scope.addNewChoice = function(id) {
     
         $scope.targetDetails;
                   i++;
                    $scope.targets.push({'pid': '','week1': '', 'week2': '','week3':'','week4':''});
                
      
     };

    $scope.removeChoice = function(val) {

       console.log("index------>",val);
                $scope.targets.splice(val,1);

     };
    //$scope.targetDetails = [];
   
     console.log("companies at targetDetails------>",$scope.companies);
    var i =0;
        $scope.addorder = function(){
          var object = {};
          object['targetss'] = $scope.targets;
          // $scope.targetDetails.push({'companies':$scope.companies,'sectors': $scope.sectors ,'customers': '','targetss': $scope.targets});
           $scope.targetDetails.push(object);
          
     }; 

           $scope.init = function () {  
               console.log("present state...",$state.current.name);
                  if($state.current.name==="monthly"){
                     $scope.getAllSectors();
                     // $scope.getnumberOfweeks();
                       $scope.getAllCompanies();
                      //  $scope.getTargetDetails();
                        //$scope.getCommentDetails();

                    }

             
             };

              $scope.init();



  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="padding: 0px" ng-repeat="details in targetDetails">
      <div class="row">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>Company</th>
             <th>Sector</th>
             <th>Customer</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           <tr >
        <td>
        
             <div>
         <select class="form-control"  data-ng-model="targetDetails.company" ng-change="getAllproductIds()" style="border: 1px solid skyblue;">
          <option value="">Select Company</option>
          <option ng-repeat="company in details.companies track  by $index" value="{{company}}" >{{company}}</option>
         </select>
         </div>
           </td>
          
         <td >
         
             <div >
                           <select class="form-control"  data-ng-model="targetDetails.sector" ng-change="getcustomers(targetDetails.sector)" style="border: 1px solid skyblue;">
             <option value="">Select Sector</option>
          <option ng-repeat=" sector in details.sectors track  by $index" value="{{sector}}">{{sector}}</option>
         </select>
         </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        
             <div >
                           <select class="form-control"  data-ng-model="targetDetails.customer" style="border: 1px solid skyblue;">
                <option value="Customer"> Customer</option>
          <option ng-repeat=" customer in details.customers track  by $index" value="{{customer}}">{{customer}}</option>
         </select>
         </div>
        </td>   
           </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table> 
    </div>

   <div class="row"  style="padding: 0px">   
   
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product Id</th>
          <th >WEEK1</th>
          <th >WEEK2</th>
          <th >WEEK3</th>
          <th >WEEK4</th>
         <!--  <th>Total</th> -->
         <!--  <th>Status</th> -->
          <th >Action</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="target in details.targetss">
       <td align="center" >
       <select class="form-control" style="width: 120px;border: 1px solid skyblue;" data-ng-model="target.pid" ng-change="getUnitsofProduct(target.pid)">
        <option value="">Select pid</option>
        <option data-ng-repeat="pid in productids">{{pid}}</option>
       </select>
       </td> 
       
        <td align="center">
                               <input class="form-control" style="width: 70px" type="text" name="" ng-model="target.week1"> 
       </td>
       <td align="center">
                               <input class="form-control" style="width: 70px" type="text" name="" ng-model="target.week2">
          </td>
       <td align="center">
                               <input class="form-control" style="width: 70px" type="text" name="" ng-model="target.week3">
       </td>
       <td align="center">
                               <input class="form-control" style="width: 70px" type="text" name="" ng-model="target.week4">
       </td>
         
       <!-- <td align="center" >
        {{ (target.week1 * 1) + (target.week2 * 1)+ (target.week3 * 1)+ (target.week4 *1)+ (target.week5 *1) }} {{target.uom}} 
       </td> -->

       <!-- <td ng-if="target.status==''"></td>
       <td ng-if="target.status==='Pending'"><span style="color: blue">{{target.status}}</span></td>
       <td ng-if="target.status==='Rejected'"><span style="color: red">{{target.status}}</span></td>
       <td ng-if="target.status==='Accepted'"><span style="color: green">{{target.status}}</span></td> -->
       
       <td align="center">
       <button class="add" style="background-color: #008CBA;" data-ng-show="$last" data-ng-click="addNewChoice($parent.$index)">+</button>
       <button class="sub" data-ng-click="removeChoice($index)" style="background-color:#f44336;margin:0px;">-</button>
       </td>
       <td>{{$parent.$index}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
            <br>

                 
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"  style="padding: 0px">
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1" >
  <button  data-ng-click="addorder()" style=" padding: 5px;margin: 0px">Add&nbsp;Order</button>
  </div>
  </div>  
   </div>
```

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can use $index for the purpose.
For example:

```
<select class="form-control"  data-ng-model="targetDetails.company[$index]" ng-change="getAllproductIds()" style="border: 1px solid skyblue;">
                                    <option value="">Select Company</option>
                                    <option ng-repeat="company in details.companies track  by $index" value="{{company}}" >{{company}}</option>
                                </select>
```

Use in ng-model:

```
data-ng-model = "targetDetails.company[$index]"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: here the product id's also affecting same way,after selecting company i will get list of product id's ,if i select product id in first set it showing as selected, and the customers also will get based on selected sector ,the json obect is created before calling getcustomers api ,so i am not able to get customers. how to do this . i am not getting any idea.

Comment: please any one give me suggestions

Comment: using the $index (`targetDetails.company[$index]`) will result in `undefined`, because `targetDetails` is an array